# Making String Comparisons Using Google Sheets Query Function

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm having trouble understanding why my query doesn't work. The result is always null unless remove C=D then I get a list of ID's. The formula will be used on a new sheet called IDS and pulls the data from Threads. My Query is:

```
=QUERY(Threads!A:D,"select A where B='No Label'and C=D",-1)
```

The table I'm trying to query looks something like this:

```
|    IDS (A)     |Labels(B) |Email List(C)      | Matching Emails(D)|
|----------------|----------|-------------------|-------------------|
|179cd3g671269f69|No Label  |pat@rus.com        |bro@rus.com        |
|179cd83p7a655449|No Label  |SCP.admi@pab.com   |mike@rus.com       |
|179cb58p79236216|No Label  |SCP.admi@pab.com   |pat@rus.com        |
|179c9er26ca777c8|No Label  |dar@rus.com        |sed@rus.com        |
|179c8l3c5b46e4ga|No Label  |dar@rus.com        |will@rus.com       |
|179c8oe73a13d487|No Label  |pat@rus.com        |dar@rus.com        |
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not working because there are no rows when values in Col C are the same as Col D.

If you want to check every row in Col C against any value in Col D, then use:

`=QUERY(Threads!A:D,"select A where B='No Label' and C matches '"&textjoin("|",true,D2:D)&"' ",1)`

`textjoin("|",true,D2:D)` brings back all the values in Col D:

`bro@rus.com|mike@rus.com|pat@rus.com|sed@rus.com|will@rus.com|dar@rus.com|pat@rus.com`

The `|` separator works as `OR`, so `bro@rus.com OR mike@rus.com...`

If needed, you could bring back a unique list if you get duplicates in future:

`textjoin("|",true,unique(D2:D))`

So the formula would be:

`=QUERY(Threads!A:D,"select A where B='No Label' and C matches '"&textjoin("|",true,unique(D2:D))&"' ",1)`

Doing a check the other way round (Col D matches in Col C):

`=QUERY(Threads!A:D,"select A where B='No Label' and D matches '"&textjoin("|",true,unique(C2:C))&"' ",1)`